# GET VIMEO VIDEO DETAILS USING JAVA - OAUTH2.0/RESTFUL

Tags: java, oauth, vimeo, scribe, signpost

I registered with "https://developer.vimeo.com/" - (Advanced API) & I have consumer key , secret etc..

I tried to get the list of videos using Scribe, SignPost Libraries. I hope vimeo implemented OAuth1.0a Version so it's asking me to visit AuthURL to produce AuthCode. Same we need to input for authorization. Now Coming to my Implementation, I need to get AuthCode (PIN/Verifier) without human interaction.

Also, Let me know if any RESTFul Service available with Vimeo Developer API.

My Programming Language: JAVA.

Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Comment: I hope people @ Stackoverflow don't know about this question :=)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at https://vimeo.com/forums/topic:34314, about ACCESS_TOKEN and ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET. The example is in php, using vimeo.php library, but I'm sure if you look up the phpVimeo function in that library, it may be translated to java.

Hope this helps and regards

Comment: I answered a bit too quickly. The example is for uploading videos, so the phpVimeo function is of no concern to you, but the ACCESS_TOKEN and ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET parameters should allow you to get authenticated without user interaction.